# horizontal menu browser compatibility

Tags: android, html, css, firefox, menu

I have created a horizontal menu to fit the full width of a container, but I have discovered that this does not work correctly in a lot of other browsers (Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari and android browsers).
The padding/ margins in these browsers are rendering too wide so the last menu item wraps outside the container making it invisible.

I would like to get it to work in as many browsers as I can, what are your suggestions to maximize compatibility?

Here is the HTML (bear in mind this has been created in Drupal, so the HTML cannot be edited):

```html
<div class=”anythingControls”>
 <ul class=”thumbnav”>
  <li class=”first”>
   <a class=”panel1” href=”#”>
    <span>Studio Products</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a class=”panel2” href=”#”>
    <span>News/Users</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a class=”panel3” href=”#”>
    <span>Events</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a class=”panel4” href=”#”>
    <span>Video</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a class=”panel5” href=”#”>
    <span>Studio Directory</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a class=”panel6” href=”#”>
    <span>Where To Buy</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class=”last”>
   <a class=”panel7 cur” href=”#”>
    <span>Talk to Us</span>
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
.anythingControls {
      background-color: #5fa0d8;
      border-left: solid 2px #5fa0d8;
      border-right: solid 2px #5fa0d8;
      border-bottom: solid 2px #5fa0d8;
      border-top: solid 1px transparent;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
      margin-top: -2px;  
      margin-bottom: 9px;
      -moz-border-radius:12px; /* Old Firefox */
      height: 40px;
      color: white;
}

.anythingControls a.cur,.anythingControls a:hover {
 background-color: #72bdfd;
 color: #ffffff
 -o-transition:color .1s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
 -ms-transition:color .1s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
 -moz-transition:color .1s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
 -webkit-transition:color .1s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
 transition:color .1s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
}

.anythingControls .last a:hover,.anythingControls .last a:active {
 margin-top: -8px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px
}

.anythingControls .first a {
 color: #5fa0d8;
    background: #ffffff;
 margin-top: -8px;
 margin-left: -3px;
 padding-top: 9px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 2px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px
}

.anythingControls .last a {
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px
}

.anythingControls ul {
   margin-left: 4px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   display: table;
}
#slideshow .anythingSlider-minimalist-round .anythingControls ul li {
 list-style: none;
    display: inline;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

#slideshow .anythingSlider-minimalist-round .anythingControls ul a {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 21px;
 margin-top: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, my boss just told me to scrap these buttons in favour of a footer instead, thanks to anyone who was going to answer this question anyway.